# Google Calendars API -- Keep seeing "The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window." every time I create an event with the script

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I wrote a script in Python that creates a Google Calendar event. However, every time I run it my browser opens up and I am greeted with "The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window." How do I avoid having to have the user authenticate each and every time the script is run? This is my code:

```
# Refer to the Python quickstart on how to setup the environment:
# https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python
# Change the scope to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' and delete any
# stored credentials.


from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
# from Google import Create_Service


def create_event(day, month, year, num_hours, start_hour):

  if len(start_hour) == 1:
    start_hour = '0' + start_hour

  end_hour = str(int(start_hour) + int(num_hours))

  if len(end_hour) == 1:
    end_hour = '0' + str(end_hour)

  start = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + start_hour + ':00:00-05:00'
  end = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + end_hour + ':00:00-05:00'

  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
  creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

  service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

  event = {
    'summary': 'Test for website',

    'start': {
      'dateTime': start,  # '2020-11-19T09:00:00-05:00',
      'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': end,  # '2020-11-19T17:00:00-05:00',
      'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
    },

  }

  event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
  service.close()
  print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))


create_event('19', '11', '2020', '5', '12')
```

I tried storing the information as shown below, but got a "KeyError: '_module'" on the line where I have     `creds = store.get()`

```
def create_event(day, month, year, num_hours, start_hour):
    if len(start_hour) == 1:
        start_hour = '0' + start_hour

    end_hour = str(int(start_hour) + int(num_hours))

    if len(end_hour) == 1:
        end_hour = '0' + str(end_hour)

    start = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + start_hour + ':00:00-05:00'
    end = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + end_hour + ':00:00-05:00'

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()

    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: Have you tried it on an entirely different computer with a different browser yet? Problems like this can be super annoying, which is why I like to rule out the computer first.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this sample procedure provided in the Google Calendar API document in saving your credentials. (Note: you need to **import pickle** in your project)

```
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python